# WKWebView changes the fonts of website randomly

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, wkwebview

I am loading a webpage in my `WKWebView` in ios application. But `WKWebview` changes all the fonts of my webpage randomly. This issue never happened before with `UIWebView`. I need to tackle this issue in XCode. How can I make sure that the correct fonts are loaded in my application.

I have tried loading the custom fonts in XCode with face font and html string.

```
        let htmlString = """
<style>
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Tahoma';
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url(Tahoma Bold.ttf);
}
</style>
<span style="font-family: 'Tahoma'; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30; color: red">(Utils.aboutUsText)</span>
"""

    landingWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
```

I expect the `WKWebview` to load the original fonts and I have to implement the solution on XCode side.

Comment: use .ttf font files instead of .otf  "src: url(data:Sans.otf;base64,FONTBASE64)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the website end where the fonts were included from an external url.